# How to generate a table, where each row represents the last day of each month?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need to generate a table with the date values that look like this:

```
01/31/2015
02/28/2015
03/31/2015
04/30/2015
....
12/31/2015
```

Each value represents the last day of each month. What is the best approach to accomplish this?

Comment: use DATEADD() to get the day before the 1st day of each month, which you construct with string concatenation.

Comment: It helps to have a calendar or number table. http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sDate is the starting date, @eDate is the ending date.

```
declare @sDate datetime,
        @eDate datetime

select  @sDate = '2013-02-25',
        @eDate = '2013-04-25'

;with cte as (
  select convert(date,left(convert(varchar,@sdate,112),6) + '01') startDate,
         month(@sdate) n
  union all
  select dateadd(month,n,convert(date,convert(varchar,year(@sdate)) + '0101')) startDate,
        (n+1) n
  from cte
  where n < month(@sdate) + datediff(month,@sdate,@edate)
)
select dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(month,1,startdate)) as enddate
from cte
```

Results:

```
2013-02-28
2013-03-31
2013-04-30
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MonthEnd = DATEADD(ms, -3, DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) + 1 + A.N, 0))
FROM (VALUES -- Feel free to replace this with some sort of numbers table
   (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)
) A (N)
```

Comment: This is a really neat solution. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. If you want to make it more flexible do what the comment says and replace the hard coded number range with a table/TVF of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can use EOMONTH to get the end of each month, and a while loop depending on when you want to stop. Of course, you can select these into a temp table or something for later use....

```
DECLARE @STARTDATE DATETIME
DECLARE @ENDDATE DATETIME

SET @STARTDATE = GETDATE()
SET @ENDDATE = '2015-12-31'

WHILE @STARTDATE < @ENDDATE
    BEGIN
        SELECT EOMONTH(@STARTDATE)
        SET @STARTDATE = DATEADD(M,+1,@STARTDATE)
    END
```